# retrieve tuple and operate over nth element(s)

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, tuples

I have a type defined and elements of this type. This elements have tuples and i need to take 3 items of this tuples and get an average over them.

```
type Name = String
type Subject = String
type Grade = Float

-- Definition of a type
type Student = (Name, Subject, Grade, Grade, Grade)

-- Elements of this type
student :: Int -> Student
student 1 = ("Rafael", "INE5416", 6.0, 5.0, 8.0)

-- now i need a function that can receive an Int as student ID, get this
-- student by ID and calculate her average grade.
getAverage :: Int -> Float
getAverage student x =  ((_, _, c, d, e) / 3) -- Int is to get x student

main = do
  print (getAverage(1)) -- passing student ID--
```

Comment: Are you sure you want `getAverage` to take an `Int`? Looks like the type should be `Student -> String`

Comment: Type aliases must start with a capital letter, just like any other type. `type Subject = String`, etc.

Comment: `student` should probably be a list `[Student]` (or possibly even a map `Data.Map.Map Int Student`) rather than a function of type `Int -> Student`.

Comment: @chepner yess, thank you for notifying. I had to translate this code and I ended up forgetting this one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pattern match on the result of calling `student` with the given ID number, and then get the average of the terms you care about.

```
getAverage :: Int -> Float
getAverage studentId = (a + b + c) / 3
  where (_, _, a, b, c) = student studentId
```

The danger is that the `student` function is not total. Evaluating `student 2` would currently crash the program.